# How to chain server calls in Angular / RxJS?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to organize my code such that one call to the server occurs after another call. I believe this is a pretty common problem, but I'm still struggling to understand other answers and apply them to my exact situation.

My component needs to go through 3 steps in this order: load, restoreState, and fetchData.

Here is my code:

```
  private load() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.endpoint1).subscribe(res => {
      this.pageTitle = res.pageTitle;
      this.pageInfo = res.pageInfo;
    })
  }

  private restoreState() {
    // restore state of page (no server calls needed)
    this.filters = this.processFilters(sessionStorage.getItem(this.pageTitle));
  }

  private fetchData() {
    this.httpClient.get(this.endpoint2, this.filters).subscribe(res => {
      this.populatePage(res);
    })
  }
```

I was thinking ngOnInit() should look something like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.load().subscribe(() => {
      this.restoreState();
      this.fetchData();
    })
  }
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to get this to work. From what I've researched, I think it may have something to do with either mergeMap() or concatMap(), but I'm not exactly sure how to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Use [switchMap](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap)

```
private load(endpoint) {
    return this.httpClient.get(endpoint);
}

private restoreState(pageTitle) {
    // restore state of page (no server calls needed)
    return this.processFilters(sessionStorage.getItem(pageTitle));
}

private fetchData(endpoint, filter) {
    return this.httpClient.get(endpoint, filter);
}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.load(this.endpoint1).pipe(
        tap(({ pageTitle }) => this.pageTitle = pageTitle),
        tap(({ pageInfo }) => this.pageInfo = pageInfo),
        map(({ pageTitle }) => this.restoreState(pageTitle)),
        tap(( filters ) => this.filters = filters),
        switchMap(( filters ) => this.fetchData(this.endpoint2, filter))
    ).subscribe( res => this.populatePage(res));
}
```